# How can I show the need to specify a value in the x axis highchart?

Tags: json, highcharts

There are the same JSON data.

I have tried to show the value in Highchart to extract values from the JSON data.

```
scope.jsondata = [
                    {
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.01",
                        "timestamp":"133409520000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 90
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.02",
                        "timestamp":"133409530000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 110
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.03",
                        "timestamp":"133409630000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 120
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.04",
                        "timestamp":"133409730000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 140
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.05",
                        "timestamp":"133409830000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 70
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.06",
                        "timestamp":"133409930000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 70
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.07",
                        "timestamp":"133410530000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 70
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.08",
                        "timestamp":"133420530000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 70
                    },{
                        "Name": "A",
                        "Categories": "03.09",
                        "timestamp":"133430530000",
                        "Locate": "1",
                        "Value": 70
                    },{
                        "Name": "B",
                        "Categories": "03.05",
                        "Locate": "2",
                        "Value": 70
                    }
                ];
```

However, Y values in the chart, but to go to the Data, Timestamp does get into the x value.

What should I Can give a timestamp value to the value of output x axis?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you need something like `data: [[<timestamp>, <value>], [<timestamp2>, <value2>]...]`.

Comment: You need to remember that timestamp should be number not string.